# Aws ec2 - how to setup load balancer to match docker container on ec2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

**Background**

I am having an EC2 instance, and a docker container running on port 3030.

In my docker container, there is a nodejs server which contain REST api setting.

I just create an Application Load Balancer with a target group(HTTP: 80) which points to above ec2 instance, in order to setup public http endpoint to send api request

The DNS name of the Load Balancer is my-docker-test-server-dev-123456789.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com.

**Problem**
I tried to send http request `POST https://my-docker-test-server-dev-123456789.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com/login`
in order to try the login api on Postman,
but error occurs

```
HTTP 504: Gateway timeout
```

**Update**
I am using default security group for my load balancer.

Inbound Rule

```
Type Protocol Port range Source Description - optional
All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0   –
All traffic All All ::/0    –
All traffic All All sg-d987a2bc / default   –
```

**Update 2**

Now updated the target group to point to HTTP:3030 as suggested by comment, but still same errors.

Health Check for the group:

```
unhealthy
Request timed out
```

**Update 3**

EC2 Instnace > Security

Inbound Rule

```
Port range Protocol   Source      Security groups
22          TCP      0.0.0.0/0    launch-wizard-9
```

Comment: What about security groups? Does you app work correctly if you access it without ALB?

Comment: @Marcin Updated the security group above. I can access the ec2 instance and the docker container in ec2 run correctly.

Comment: If your docker works on 3030, why your target group uses port 80?

Comment: @Marcin Updated the target groups port to 3030, but still same error

Comment: Can you provide more details. What are SGs for the instance. I think you posted only for ALB? How do you test your application? Using curl? Are you trying to use HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: @Marcin updated the SGs for the instance and the testing method is using Postman as mentioned above. thanks

Comment: Your SG for instance only allows port 20. You are missing port 3030.

Comment: @Marvin It works now! I think I'm still a bit confusing of the relationship of ELB and instance, and the security group. Can you provide a brief explanation in comment so that I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was by incorrectly set security group (SG) of the instances and the target group (TG) port. In the first case, since the docker application is exposed on the port 3030 on the instance, SG must allow inbound traffic on that port. The **inbound SG rule was missing**.

In the TG case, the original traffic port was 80. However, since the docker works at port 3030, TG port needed to be change to port 3030.

So the traffic looks as follows:

```
Clinet ---(HTTP:80) ---> ALB ---> TG --- (HTTP:3030) ---> Instance with docker on port 3030
```