# AWS ALB - not reaching docker container

Tags: docker, http, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a react app running inside a docker container and mapped to port 80 of the ec2 instance
`docker run -d --name react -p80:3000`

When I try to access it via the ec2 instance Public IPv4 address everything works fine.
When I use a **Network** Load Balancer listening on **TCP** port 80 and forwarding to **TCP** port 80 everything works fine.
When I use an **Application** Load Balancer listening on **HTTP** port 80 and forwarding to **HTTP** port 80 my react app becomes unreachable.

Why can't I use the HTTP protocol and as a consequence an Application Load Balancer?

I have read this question and followed the steps listed with no luck:
[Aws ec2 - how to setup load balancer to match docker container on ec2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66864290/aws-ec2-how-to-setup-load-balancer-to-match-docker-container-on-ec2-instance)

Comment: Does the security group associated with the application load balancer allow traffic from your ip?

Comment: Yes, inbound rules of the ALB allow all traffic. No restrictions.

Comment: Does the security group associated with the instance allow traffic from the security group associated with the load balancer?

Comment: Yes, it allows HTTP type traffic on port 80 from anywhere.

Comment: you need to explicitly whitelist the load balancer security group

Comment: Done that now and it doesn't change anything, still unreachable.

Comment: I don't have Nginx in front of my react docker container. Would that be the reason for the problem I'm having?

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the two security groups?

Comment: it turns out the ALB security group settings were wrong. The inbound rules. The problem was that the ALB got automatically assigned the _default_ security group which for some reason had incorrect rules.
Bottom line, do not ever modify default sg because they get assigned to AWS services when you don't create a new one!

Comment: Yes, it had to be a security group issue

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, someone must have tempered with the default sg (probably me months ago) and I was starting to shift my attention elsewhere.